# Selenium webdriver tooltip text on mouse over

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am trying to find tooltip text when I mouse hover webelement, but I am not able to get the tooltip text.

Code:

```
Actions a=new Actions(driver);  
a.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/p[8]/a"))).build().perform();
String ToolTipText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/p[8]//a")).getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(" tool  "+ToolTipText);
```

I am able to hover over just not able to find tooltip text
HTML code:

```
<p>
The tooltip can use each elements title attribute.
<a class="easyui-tooltip tooltip-f" title="" href="#">Hover me</a>
 to display tooltip.
</p>
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems with your code.

1. **Fix your locator** in the `ToolTipText` to the same one as in your first call: `html/body/p[8]/a` (this xpath says find the children of the eighth `p` and not any descendant as in `//a`). It would be even better if you use a class parameter that holds this locator (or an improved locator, see example) and use it.
2. The `title` attribute in your HTML **is empty**, so no wonder you get nothing.
3. If it's a `title` attribute type of tooltip and not one that's
   generated with CSS, then you don't need to hover the element to get
   the tooltip. If it's a non trivial tooltip, like the one when you hover a tag in StackOverflow, than after hovering with `Actions` like you did, you need to find the tooltip in the HTML.

Example:

```
private By tooltipElementBy = By.cssSelector("a.easyui-tooltip.tooltip-f");

String ToolTipText = driver.findElement(tooltipElementBy).getAttribute("title");
```